# Blender: Advanced character rig problem

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints

As the title says, I'm having an issue regarding my 3D-characters rig.

INFO: As you can see in the pictures below, my character has swords attached to his back. Each sword is connected to the hand using a child of constraint so I that I can make him grab the swords by setting the influence value to 1. In addition to that, both of the swords are parented to the upper-chest bone, so that they will follow the character as he moves.

PROBLEM: Now as I change the influence to 1 so that the hand is now controlling the sword, everything works as I want it to. I can move the hand to the wanted location, and the sword will follow it. However! When I move the chest, the sword will start to rotate around the upper-chests pivot point since that's where it's parented to from the beginning. Is there anyway I can get around this problem? If so, I'd be glad to know.

The problem is demonstrated in the pictures below.

PICTURE1: Both swords are parented to the upper chest bone, making them move togheter as I lean his upper chest forwards. *Had to delete this picture since it didn't allow me to use more than 2 links/Pictures*

PICTURE2: Set the child of constraint influence to 1 in order for the hand to fully controll the sword bone. I rotate the arm.

PICTURE3: As I rotate the chest, the swordbone starts to take another path compared to the hand! (problem)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get double transformations:

- 1st from child_of
- 2nd from parent

When you enable the child_of for the hand, you need to disable the original parent. As this is not possible from pose mode, you need to make this relationship with child_of too, and switch between them in one frame when you need to change the parenting.